# WordPress jQuery Return 0 on mobile browser but working fine on desktop browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to get an AJAX response in WordPress it's working fine on my desktop/laptop but on mobile phone and tablet browsers, it returns 0.
**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        var current_work_id = '<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "get",
            dataType : "json",
            url : my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data : {action: "my_action", post_id : current_work_id},
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
                if(response.type == "success") {
                    console.log('counted');
                }else {
                    console.log('not counted');
                }
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        }); 
    });
```

WordPress

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
function my_action_callback() {
        $result["type"] = "success";
        $result["data"] = 'demo';
        echo json_encode($result, true);
    wp_die();
}
```

Same code working fine on my laptop and other laptops too. But when I test the website on my mobile it alerts 0.

Answer (score 0):

This code wrong `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );`.

You need to use `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );`

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback() {
      $result["type"] = "success";
      $result["data"] = 'demo';
      echo json_encode($result, true);
  wp_die();
}
```

Seems type error `my_action_callback`